# Compute amount of numbers between 2 values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have already read several questions about this subject but I can not find a good answer to my specific question.

I have the list:

```
l = [0.25, 0.875, 0.7, 0.175, 0.6, 0.55, 0.525]
```

I have to write a method that returns a list of integers as result, namely the number of A scores, the number of B scores and the number of C scores, respectively. An A score is a score that is at least 60%, and a C score is a score that is strictly less than 50%. All other scores are B scores.

So, the list we need to create is:

```
[3, 2, 2]
```

I've tried working with this code:

```
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        for i in l:
            if i>=0.6:
                a+=1
            elif i<0.5:
                c+=1
            else:
                b+=1
        return [a,b,c]
```

Does anyone know if there is a better solution to this problem?

Comment: A quick "hack" to fix your approach would be `[sum(1 for i in l if i > 0.6)]` but you'd need to do this for each condition, which will lead to in efficiency (multiple traverses over the list). You are better off using a simple, explicit `for` loop.

Comment: Can you sort the list, or do you have a much larger list that would be inefficient to sort?

Comment: In my opinion "the shortest" solution is seldomly the best. I belong to the Group that prefers readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me, I adapted your original idea.

```
[sum(1 for i in l if i >= 0.6) ,sum(1 for i in l if i < 0.6 and i>=0.5), sum(1 for i in l if i < 0.5 )
```

It gives you:

```
[3,2,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

sum() computes the sum of its arguments but i > 0.6 returns a bool

What you really want is to get the length of the sub array that passes a test

This is one way of getting the number of A-scores

```
len([i for i in l if i >= 0.6])
```

Comment: i'd prefer `sum(1 for i in l if i >= 0.6)`. that way do not have to create an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 1):

not very concise but pretty self-explaining using [`itertools.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

l = [0.25, 0.875, 0.7, 0.175, 0.6, 0.55, 0.525]

def abc(score):
    if score < 0.5:
        return 'C'
    elif score < 0.6:
        return 'B'
    return 'A'

scores = Counter(abc(scr) for scr in l)
print(scores)  # Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 2})

lst = [scr for abc, scr in sorted(scores.items())]
print(lst)  # [3, 2, 2]
```

this counts all the grades while iterating once over your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l = [0.25, 0.875, 0.7, 0.175, 0.6, 0.55, 0.525]

a_scores = [i for i in l if i >= 0.6]

b_scores = [i for i in l if i < 0.6 and i >= 0.5]

c_scores = [i for i in l if i < 0.5]
```

Output:

```
[0.875, 0.7, 0.6]

[0.55, 0.525]

[0.25, 0.175]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension here to first map the scores to the grades.  You can make a function to assign a score to each grade like this:

```
def assign_grade(x):
    if x >= 0.6:
        return 'A'
    elif x < 0.50:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'B'
```

where x is the score that will be input.  Then you can call that function for each item in the list:

```
grades = [assign_grade(x) for x in scores]
```

Based on your example above grades would be a list of the grades for each score, ['C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']

To get the count for each grade you can use the count function:

```
grade_sums = [grades.count(x) for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

which returns [3, 2, 2]

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate it. It is much better to write simple, understandable, and quick code than flashy code.

```
scores = [0.25, 0.875, 0.7, 0.175, 0.6, 0.55, 0.525]

a = b = c = 0

for score in scores:
    if score >= 0.6:
        a += 1
    elif score < 0.5:
        c += 1
    else:
        b += 1

tallies = [a, b, c]
```

The above code executes more quickly than other more complicated code.

You could also have the list to begin with:

```
abc = [0, 0, 0]
...
abc[0] += 1
```

Or a dictionary:

```
abc = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
...
abc['a'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Another SO-user, this I Think is the way to go:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [0.25, 0.875, 0.7, 0.175, 0.6, 0.55, 0.525]

def assign_grade(x):
    if x >= 0.6:
        return 'A'
    elif x < 0.50:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'B'

Counter([assign_grade(item) for item in l])
```

Returns a dict

```
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 2})
```